# JavaScript equivalent to .NET's Enum.HasFlag()

Tags: javascript, typescript, enum-flags

My .NET backend handle enum authorization with HasFlag()

```
Enum Foo {
  0: Zero,
  1: One,
  2: Two,
  3: Three,
  ..
}

5.HasEnum(Foo.One) is falsy because 5 is equal to 3 + 2
6.HasEnum(Foo.One) is truthy because 6 is equal to 3 + 2 + 1
```

How to handle it in JavaScript ?

I'm receiving a rôle (that is > 0 and < 1048), how to know if it has 32 rôle ?

Comment: but Enums don't exist in JS. What are you working on? An Object?

Comment: You can create a function and put it on `Number` prototype. But its better to use your own construct

Comment: I'm receiving 64 e.g, how to know if it has 32 inside it ? I'm using TypeScript enums but it doesn't work like in .NET tho

Comment: maybe you are talking about Typescript? if so, you can do a function that does the bitwise comparison

Answer (score -1):

```
declare global {
    interface Number {
        hasFlag(flag: number): boolean;
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'hasFlag', {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    value: function (flag: number) { return (this & flag) === flag; }
});
```

```js
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'hasFlag', {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    value: function (flag) { return (this & flag) === flag; }
});


document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = "(3).hasFlag(1) = " + (3).hasFlag(1);
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML += "<br>(4).hasFlag(1) = " + (4).hasFlag(1);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

If you are using plain JS, don't do declare global and remove the ":number" signature.